# Control ESSP8266 IOT board over cellphone hotspot wifi

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am using the following code in order to control my `ESP8266` using my cellphone hotspot.

```
/*
 * ESP8266 NodeMCU LED Control over WiFi Demo
 *
 * 
 */
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

//ESP Web Server Library to host a web page
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

//---------------------------------------------------------------
//Our HTML webpage contents in program memory
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
<h1>by J.Mehdinia</h1><br>
Ciclk to turn <a href="ledOn" target="myIframe">LED ON</a><br>
Ciclk to turn <a href="ledOff" target="myIframe">LED OFF</a><br>
LED State:<iframe name="myIframe" width="100" height="25" frameBorder="0"><br>
<hr>
</center>

</body>
</html>
)=====";
//---------------------------------------------------------------
//On board LED Connected to GPIO2
int LED=5;  

//SSID and Password of your WiFi router
const char* ssid = "Jms";
const char* password = "ab12";

//Declare a global object variable from the ESP8266WebServer class.
ESP8266WebServer server(80); //Server on port 80

//===============================================================
// This routine is executed when you open its IP in browser
//===============================================================
void handleRoot() {
 Serial.println("You called root page");
 String s = MAIN_page; //Read HTML contents
 server.send(200, "text/html", s); //Send web page
}

void handleLEDon() {
 Serial.println("LED on page");
 digitalWrite(LED,HIGH); //LED is connected in reverse
 server.send(200, "text/html", "ON"); //Send ADC value only to client ajax request
}

void handleLEDoff() { 
 Serial.println("LED off page");
 digitalWrite(LED,LOW); //LED off
 server.send(200, "text/html", "OFF"); //Send ADC value only to client ajax request
}
//==============================================================
//                  SETUP
//==============================================================
void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);     //Connect to your WiFi router
  Serial.println("");

  //Onboard LED port Direction output
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT); 
  //Power on LED state off
  digitalWrite(LED,LOW);

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  //If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //IP address assigned to your ESP

  server.on("/", handleRoot);        //Which routine to handle at root location. This is display page
  server.on("/ledOn", handleLEDon);  //as Per  <a href="ledOn">, Subroutine to be called
  server.on("/ledOff", handleLEDoff);

  server.begin();                  //Start server
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}
//==============================================================
//                     LOOP
//==============================================================
void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();          //Handle client requests
}
```

Everything works fine by using `ESP8266` IP address in an html page through devices that use my shared hotspot to connect to the Internet. But I can't access that html page by using internet coming from other internet access points. I'm new to `ESP8266`. What is the reason and how may I solve it? I don't have another kind of internet access to test now.

Comment: I doubt you have a public IP address for the device so it effectively behind a firewall router - your phone.

Comment: I have that ip and i use that to access my ESP from browser.

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @user: "I have that IP ..." What IP? The local one or the Internet one? Alex's answer is correct.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about network routing and firewalls, not about electrical engineering.  The most common solution to this problem in *commercial* products is to pass messages through a cloud server visible to both gadgets and computers/phones on all consumer networks, since that is the only method that avoids needing to make configuration changes to the networks involved.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an electronics question, rather a networks one.

To put it simply, when connected to a router (here, your phone), a device has a private - or local - address, which you use when connecting with devices also using your phone's hotspot, or network. They are usually between `192.168.0.0` and `192.168.255.255` or `10.0.0.0` and `10.255.255.255`. The private address is usually provided by your router, via a DHCP server. 
To connect to the internet and browse websites such as stackexchange, you need a public address, which is provided by your Internet Service Provider (ISP) to your router. When accessing the Internet, all of the devices connected to the same router will send requests to the router, which will then forward the request to the Internet. As a result, all of the devices connected to the same router will access the internet with the same public address.

This means that you can't access a device via its private IP with another device on another router, because they are completely different networks and one's private addresses don't mean anything to the other. By creating a hotspot with your phone, you created what is called an intranet. As it is, you can't access it with its public address either, because there are several devices on the same address, and the router won't be able to know which device you want to connect to if you only use the IP address.

In your case, you won't be able to access your board from another network, as cellphone networks are restrictive. However, if you have a home network (not your phone but a regular ISP), you might be able to setup **port forwarding** to access your device from other access points, with the public address of the router. However, the exact procedure is different for each ISP so you will have to do a bit of research.